# Queries too slow with Postgresql full text search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search

I have seeded the database with 10,000 records to create more realistic conditions. I am using postgresql full text search and the queries are between 3-4 sec. I am searching against model and also an association. The association is set up where a user has_many scoreboards and each scoreboard has_one user.

Below is the code from the server queries.

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered search/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3315.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3583ms (Views: 287.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3290.1ms)
```

The model code is given below.

```
include PgSearch
   pg_search_scope :search_by_scoreboard, 
                    :against => [:name_of_scoreboard, :name_of_organization, :name_of_activity],
                    associated_against: {user: [:name, :email]},

                    :using => {
                        :tsearch => {
                            :prefix => true,
                            :dictionary => "english",
                            :any_word => true
                        }

                    }
```

The controller and the view code is also given below.

```
def index
   @scoreboard_search = Scoreboard.search_by_scoreboard(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
end 



<div id="search">
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "search scorecliq!" %>
  <div id="searchbutton">
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div>


<% @scoreboard_search.each do |scoreboard_search| %>
    <%= div_for scoreboard_search, :class => "inner-disp" do %> 
        Scoreboard: <%= link_to "#{scoreboard_search.name_of_scoreboard}", scoreboard_path(scoreboard_search.id) %><br>
        Organization: <%= scoreboard_search.name_of_organization %><br>
        Activity: <%= scoreboard_search.name_of_activity %><br>
        Admin: <%= link_to "#{scoreboard_search.user.name}", user_path(scoreboard_search.user.id)  %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @scoreboard_search, :page_links => false %>
```

I have read the documentation for pg_search gem and seen the rails cast on it as well. The documentation says it would be impossible to speed up searches with indexes if you are searching through an association. The text below is from the pg_search documentation.

```
It is possible to search columns on associated models. Note that if you do this, it will be impossible to speed up searches with database indexes. However, it is supported as a quick way to try out cross-model searching.
```

Is it possible to speed up the searches. I have seen the rails cast and he uses indexes to speed up searches. I am not sure if that would work in my case considering the documentation says its impossible. However, I am sure there must be some way to speed up the queries to under 500ms. I am not too sure how to go about doing that. Any help on how to speed up the queries with pg_search full_text would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

ddl table with indexes definition for the users and scoreboards table.

```
Table "public.scoreboards"
        Column        |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         
----------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                     | not null default nextval('scoreboards_id_seq'::regclass)
 name_of_scoreboard   | character varying           | 
 name_of_organization | character varying           | 
 name_of_activity     | character varying           | 
 user_id              | integer                     | 
 created_at           | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at           | timestamp without time zone | not null
 states               | character varying           | 
 country              | character varying           | 
 cities               | character varying           | 
Indexes:
    "scoreboards_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_scoreboards_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
    "index_scoreboards_on_user_id_and_created_at" btree (user_id, created_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_09668734c5" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "comments" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5cb64542d4" FOREIGN KEY (scoreboard_id) REFERENCES scoreboards(id)

                                     Table "public.users"


    Column       |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
-------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 name              | character varying           | 
 email             | character varying           | 
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 password_digest   | character varying           | 
 remember_digest   | character varying           | 
 admin             | boolean                     | default false
 activation_digest | character varying           | 
 activated         | boolean                     | default false
 activated_at      | timestamp without time zone | 
 reset_digest      | character varying           | 
 reset_sent_at     | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_users_on_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "scoreboards" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_09668734c5" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
:
```

Comment: could you please provide ddl with indexes definition `\d tablename` in psql ?

Comment: @DmitrySavinkov, I'll edit my original question. I'll provide ddl with indexes definition for users table and scoreboards table. First time I ran that command. I hope I got what you wanted